# Asp net core api Clean Architecture проблема с встраиванием сервисов

Tags: c#, .net, service, dependency-injection

DependencyInjection.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using TestApi.Application.Common.Interfaces;
using TestApi.Infrastructure.Identity;
using TestApi.Infrastructure.Persistence;

namespace TestApi.Infrastructure;

public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddPersistence(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        
        services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => 
            provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
        
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        
        services.AddTransient<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();

        
        
        return services;
    }
}
```

IdentityService.cs - с ним проблема

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using TestApi.Application.Common.Interfaces;
using TestApi.Application.Common.Models;

namespace TestApi.Infrastructure.Identity;

public class IdentityService : IIdentityService
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly Mapper _mapper;
 
    public IdentityService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, Mapper mapper)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Register(RegisterModel registerModel)
    {
        var user = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(registerModel);

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, registerModel.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded) return false;
        
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проект выдаёт ошибку при добавлении этого сервиса  services.AddTransient<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();

Comment: Вам действительно нужно каждый раз создавать сервис при обращении к нему? Может можно заменить на `AddSingleton` или `AddScoped`? Нашёл хорошую статью про разницу https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/539762/. А так, добавьте в вопрос, какую ошибку выдаёт, чтоб было проще ответить на вопрос

Comment: Я нашёл проблему, забыл зарегестрировать AutoMapper